# Integer() in 64bit XE2

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

How would this be correct when on 64bit platform in XE2?

```
type
  PRGB24 = ^TRGB24;
  TRGB24 = packed record
    B: Byte;
    G: Byte;
    R: Byte;
  end;

var
  s1: pRGB24;
  ptrD: integer;

....

inc(Integer(s1), PtrD); <- gives error here "Left side cannot be assigned to"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer type is 32-bit long, pointer type is 64-bit long on 64-bit platform, hence the error. I can't test it now, but

```
inc(NativeInt(s1), PtrD);
```

should fix the problem.

---

BTW: `Inc` procedure can accept pointers, so normally there is no need to cast pointer to integer here. The same result can be obtained by

```
inc(PByte(s1), PtrD);
```

To avoid `s1` casting at all is even better

```
inc(s1, PtrD);
```

but it changes the meaning of the code - its equivalent is

```
inc(PByte(s1), PtrD * SizeOf(TRGB24 ));
```

Comment: inc does accept pointers but of course the meaning changes. So I'd say you are always better off avoiding the integer cast, but take care.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst `NativeInt` will get the job done I would rather cast it to `PByte`:

```
inc(PByte(s1), PtrD);
```

Since `s1` is a pointer, casting to another pointer is more natural – it's not possible for there to be a pointer width error now or in the future.